# Do a search using a dropdownlist in php where the values are from the database

Tags: php, search, drop-down-menu, using

Guys i do really need your help... I don't have any idea on how to make a search and display the results in tabular form using the dropdown list where the values in the dropdownlist came from the database. Here is the scenario... When i choose one of the options or choices from the dropdownlist(for example Closed - Closed is the status from the cases) when i click closed it will display results in tabular form from those cases that has a status equivalent to closed so as the same with the other statuses when there is no match it will display a message. (It would be nice that when the values from the dropdownlist are came from the database so that in the future you can add another status it will automatically populate in the dropdownlist that would be also nice if I do the same in the search...) I hope guys you help me in this one...